# How can I change the socket timeout for a half-processed request in Apache httpcore NIO?

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

Say you have an application based on Apache HttpComponents, which handles regular requests and long polling requests ("comet"). By using NHttpRequestHandler you can delay the response for some requests and send the response immediately for other requests.

But how can you achieve a short socket timeout for the regular requests and a longer one for long polling requests? In some cases it may not be easy to tell the difference between the two types of request without beginning to process them. From testing it appears that setting a new timeout on the request object with setParams() will not affect the timeout. Same for the response object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can set socket timeout value on the underlying HTTP connection by using `HttpConnection#setSocketTimeout` method.